# How to typeset my reference of an article like the attached image

Tags: bibliographies

[image]

the above image shows how I am to typeset my reference to an article. I have no reference style that has this in history so I decided to type. Even at that, I can not get it right on LaTeX article class. More to it I am using two-column document.

Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
{[Bed88]\hspace{2cm}} {\textbf{M. A. and Bednarrczyk} - \textit{Category of asynchronous system}, PhD thesis,University of Sussex, 1988.
\end{document}
```

I do not know how to make the lines that follow the first to be indented 2cm left.

Comment: Are you familiar with the bibliography style called `alpha`?

Comment: @Mico not at all, I search to see the alpha 'style' of a thing but I add [\bibliographystyle{alpha}] to my latex code, no change was made. I use 'natbib' anyway. I will appreciate if you can give me a link that will teach me how to use this 'alpha'

Comment: After you added the directive `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`, did you perform a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more)? Incidentally, `natbib` is (primarily) a citation management package; it does not govern how bibliographic entries are formatted.

Comment: @Mico yes, I did compiled it far more than two times after I added \bibliographystyle{alpha} but no change

Comment: I'm really confused now: Are you not using BibTeX to construct your bibliography (and the citation call-outs)? That's what I was assuming until now, but I may have misunderstood your setup.

Comment: @Mico, what I used is natbib not BibTeX. If you like to show me how to migrate from natbib to BibTeX  so long it will make me to achieve this type of reference style, I will appreciate it.

Comment: `natbib` is not a substitute for BibTeX. `natbib` is a LaTeX package; BibTeX is an external program. To "migrate from natbib to BibTeX" is not possible -- or even meaningful. At this stage, your time is probably best spent consulting an introduction to bibliography creation under LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

For your manual approach, a table might be helpful:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}@{}p{5.5cm}}
[Bed88] & \textbf{M. A. and Bednarrczyk} - \textit{Category of asynchronous system}, PhD thesis,University of Sussex, 1988.\\

[Ced88] & \textbf{M. A. and Bednarrczyk} - \textit{Category of asynchronous system}, PhD thesis,University of Sussex, 1988.\\
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]